# Does IntelliJ Ultimate include Webstorm and Appcode

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm wondering if the Webstorm & Appcode IDEs come bundled with the ultimate edition.

Comment: Yes for WebStorm, but I still don't know for AppCode.

Answer (score 3):

From the JetBrains website:

> **IntelliJ IDEA vs WebStorm features**
>
> IntelliJ IDEA remains JetBrains' flagship product and IntelliJ IDEA provides full JavaScript
> support along with all other features of WebStorm via bundled or
> downloadable plugins. The only thing missing is the simplified project
> setup.

AppCode is MacOS only, because it relies on an XCode installation, and MacOS X specific features (like the iOS Simulator, MacOS X keychain, etc)

Therefore it is a separate project. It also requires a separate license.